# check if a value exists in array of constants in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some predefined values like

```
declare 
v_type varchar2(20);
begin
    select type into v_type from GenericTypes where id =5 ;
   // say v_type = 'XYZ'

end;
```

Now, i have to check if v_type is equal to 'ABC' or 'DEF' or 'ASD' and 5 more items.

so i used:
`if v_type = 'ABC' or v_type ='DEF' or v_type='ASD'` and 5 more conditions

If there is any more efficient method to do this like using select exist etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the IN clause for example:

```
if v_type IN ('ABC','DEF','ASD') then
  do things;
end if;
```

Comment: much more simple than expected. feeling like dumb

Answer (score 1):

You could use **CASE** expression and check the condition in the query itself.

For example,

```
DECLARE
  v_type NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN TYPE IN ('ABC','DEF','ASD')
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END GenericTypes
  INTO v_type
  WHERE ID  =5;
  IF v_type = 1 THEN
    -- do somethins
  END IF;
END;
/
```